# Blender key swap from c++ to Python

Tags: python, autohotkey

I have an autohotkey script that reads the active window and swaps the key press from alt to spacebar, making it soo much easier to navigate the viewport. I'd like to know how to convert the c++ simply to Python, so it can be called as the program runs, executing that keymap py. Here's the code, thanks in advance.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class GHOST_WindowClass
LAlt::Space
Space::LAlt
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really can't make any sense of this question. Could you try to explain it better?

Comment: "how to convert the c++ simply to Python" im not seeing any c++

Comment: Sorry, I thought that autohotkey code was c++? What language is it?

Comment: @0x464e Apologies for the confusion. I thought that the autohotkey script was c++. In short I'd like to be able to run a similar script in python, so I can add it into the py keymap python file, and not have to run the autohotkey script everytime I use Blender. Thanks.

Comment: AutoHotkey code is AutoHotkey code, not C++. And about remapping in Python, I don't know, sorry.